# How to remove nodes from an XML file

Tags: xml, groovy, xmlslurper

I want to remove some elements from an XML file using groovy, however this does not seem to work.

Any ideas how to solve this?

```
def DeploymentDescriptors = new XmlSlurper().parse("pathToMyXMLFile")
DeploymentDescriptors.NameValuePairs.NameValuePair.each {
if(it.name == 'B')
   it.replaceNode{}
}
```

**XML File**

```
<DeploymentDescriptors>
    <NameValuePairs>
        <NameValuePair>
            <name>A</name>
            <value>Value A</value>
        </NameValuePair>
        <NameValuePair>
            <name>B</name>
            <value>Value B</value>
        </NameValuePair>
        <NameValuePair>
            <name>C</name>
            <value>Value C</value>
        </NameValuePair>
    </NameValuePairs>
</DeploymentDescriptors>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XmlSlurper` doesn't change the processed XML until there's a need. If You serialize it You'll see the effect.

Here's working example:

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
def xml = """
<DeploymentDescriptors>
    <NameValuePairs>
        <NameValuePair>
            <name>A</name>
            <value>Value A</value>
        </NameValuePair>
        <NameValuePair>
            <name>B</name>
            <value>Value B</value>
        </NameValuePair>
        <NameValuePair>
            <name>C</name>
            <value>Value C</value>
        </NameValuePair>
    </NameValuePairs>
</DeploymentDescriptors>"""

def parsed = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
parsed.NameValuePairs.NameValuePair.findAll { it.name.text() == 'B' }*.replaceNode{}
println XmlUtil.serialize(new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
  mkp.yield parsed
} )
```

Comment: Function `find` finds the first value matching the closure condition. So if there are two nodes with name 'B' you will remove only 1. OP used `each`, so i suppose he wanted to remove ALL occurences.

Comment: Thanks @xwid for pointing this out. Replaced `find` with `each` and conditional block.

Comment: You should use `findAll` instead of `each`.

Comment: Edited. However, not sure what the real intention of OP was.

Comment: OP used word "elements" so I suppose he meant more than 1.